# NODE.JS Twitch bot function fetch gets the job done but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have been looking through other threads were it seems that using return is supposed to give the value to the parent function. But my code below always return Undefined.

I get the feeling this is because of the timing of the code. (sync and async something something, Still reading on this)

So my question is if any of you can see what is going wrong and if you could nudge me in the right direction (or straight out give me the answer with documentation links as well).

Thank you!

```
const tmi = require("tmi.js");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const doubleCommand = message.toLowerCase().split(" ");

// This function calls the code to be executed
if (doubleCommand[0] === "!shoutout" || doubleCommand[0] === "!so") {
    console.log(isUser(doubleCommand[1], channel));
  }

//This funktion checks to see if doubleCommand[1] is a existing user
function isUser(userLookUp, channel) {
  fetch(
    `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${userLookUp.toLowerCase().trim()}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${O_Token}`,
        "Client-Id": C_ID
      }
    }
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data !== "undefined") { // Here i check to see if there was a user and if there was i check what game they are/were playing.
        fetch(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id=${res.data[0].id}`,
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${O_Token}`,
              "Client-Id": C_ID
            }
          }
        )
          .then(result => result.json())
          .then(result => {
            return res.data[0].game_name
          });
      } else {
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think converting your code to the `async/await` pattern will make it more readable and help you track down the issue. Of course you can always put some `console.log` statements in your code (and probably find out it returns before completing all operations).

The code would go from something like

```js
function doStuffThen() {
    fetch(...).then(res => {
        fetch(...).then(res => {
            fetch(...).then(res => {
                // etc etc
            });
        });
    });
}
```

To something like

```js
async function doStuffAsync() {
    let data1 = await fetch(...);
    let data2 = await fetch(...);
    let data3 = await fetch(...);
    return someResult;
}
```

In the end, I'm not sure what the *exact* problem is here, but I'd definitely recommend moving towards async/await and debugging from there.

Comment: Thank you, When I did this with let data1 i got a error message about await and something sync. I will see if i can duplicate it and share it with you

Comment: One thing to note is that your call to `isUser` will only resolve after some time now, so you can't immediately `console.log` it. You can choose to `await` it as well, or use `then` to print after it resolves.

Comment: Thank you @fravolt ! I changed the code to this format and now it works. Sadly my response took so long since I had 
`let data1 = await fetch(Data[0].smth)`
instead of
`let data1 = await fetch(data[0].smth)`
and that was throwing errors since .Data[0] doesn't exist while .data[0] does.